# Green's theorem, must $F$ be defined on $C$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In green's theorem, must the vector field $F$ be defined on the boundary curve?

For example, if $C$ is the closed curve $x= y^2$ with $x=1$, oriented clockwise. $F = (y^3-lnx)i + (\sqrt{y^2 +1} + 3x)j$. Is it valid to calculate this with Green's theorem?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the line integral makes no sense.